# Is it possible to create new fields using django admin page interface?

Tags: python, django, backend

Is it possible to create and delete new charfields or textareas through the Django admin page without harcoding them?

For example, I have a simple model, registered in Django admin page

```
class DocumentList(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Obviously, it has only one charfield on admin page, something like:

```
DocumentList: [___________]
```

How can I add another one and delete her later if needed from Django admin page without actually hardcoding another charfield/textarea in `models.py`, to make it look like:

```
DocumentList: [___________]

*****************[___________]
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom form in the admin, either by using the [`form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form) option of the [`get_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) method. This is the documentation example for how you'd pass a custom `form`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp.models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        exclude = ['name']

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['age']
    form = PersonForm
```

You can add extra fields, as in any form.

I was wondering why you wanted this. Since you said in a comment it is to submit information to an API, you can also use an [action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/), taking input from the user in [an intermediate page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages).

---

**EDIT**: As became apparent in comments, the form needs to be dynamic for the user, and not when it is created. Therefore, the solution is using [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines), which once created and linked to the current model, allow the user to add any number of related forms to the current form.

Comment: I mean changing number of fields dynamically using django admin interface

Comment: Oh. You can do that with [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines), and then you get a link to add more _forms_ dynamically. If that's adequate (i.e. each form would have a field, or a few fields, that you want to add dynamically), it will work, although I think it's a bit of a hack. You could also do that in the intermediate page of the admin action.

Comment: Thank you, your proposal actually fixed my problem - i used inlines and it is actually what i wanted

Comment: Great! I'll move the comment to the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Django models are not meant to be dynamically altered. You have to explicitly add the fields on your model, run migrations to have the fields created in your database backend, and reload your server process (`./manage.py runserver` does this automatically).

If you want to create a model that can hold an arbitrary amount of text strings instead of just one or a fixed amount, you need to use a many-to-many relation to another model.

Comment: But is there any way to dynamically alter content on django admin page (i am using it to send it to API)?

Comment: What do you mean by " dynamically alter content"? You change change the value of the field through the Django admin, but not the number of fields, dynamically.

Comment: My bad, I've meant to change number of fields dynamically on django admin page